# Vuforia Web Service API

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have a problem while making Augmented Reality App. I have to make back end (website) for manage marker data that can create, read, update, and delete. I really don't know how to make this back end. Anyone have example code for back end website?

Comment: This question is too broad. SO is not a forum, please find a forum for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the question is really too broad, and Vuforia has a forum for it - I'll help you out this time. Vuforia has a page specifically for that: [How To Use the Vuforia Web Services API](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Use-the-Vuforia-Web-Services-API)  . In this page you can find links to all the API documentation, and also links to php example which is probably a lead on the direction you were seeking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PHP class with basic operations like create, read, and delete for Vuforia Cloud Recognition. 
https://github.com/FionNoir/VuforiaClient

I've used it for a server backend that communicates with Vuforia and which  provide all necessary data for an Unity game.